# Have the same radio button at two places

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I want to have a group of radio buttons, so that one of them appears twice.
The result would look like this:

[image]

The tricky point is that I want to achieve this in **pure HTML/CSS** (although I doubt CSS will help here).

Here is the code I wrote to produce the four radio buttons above:

```html
<input type="radio" name="buttons" value="choice1" id="button1"/>
<label for="button1">Choice 1</label>

<input type="radio" name="buttons" value="choice1" id="button1"/>
<label for="button">Choice 1</label>

<input type="radio" name="buttons" value="choice2" id="button3"/>
<label for="button3">Choice 2</label>

<input type="radio" name="buttons" value="choice3" id="button4"/>
<label for="button4">Choice 3</label>
```

I naively thought that attributing the same value to the first to buttons would make them behave as one, but of course it doesn't.

Is it possible to achieve this behaviour without any JS?

---

**Edit**

This might sound strange, so here's my usecase.
What I ultimately want is to have a radio button storing a global state, and have access to it at multiple places.

For instance, suppose the following snippet:

```css
.state-repeater {
    visibility: hidden;
}


#button.state-repeater:checked > p {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="button" />
<label for="button">Button</label>

<!--
Lots of blocks; the two parts are totally uncorrelated;
so the classical sibling selector tricks do not work
-->

<input class="state-repeater" type=radio id="button" />
<p>The button is checked</p>
```

I want the `<p>` tag text to turn blue when the radio button is checked; however, due to the radio button being far from it, I need some kind of repeater.
Obviously, the approach of this snippet does not work.

Is it possible to "repeat" the information that the radio button is checked?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use JS. There is no pure way. Maybe wrap the radio in an element that LOOKS like 2 radio buttons and when clicked they both LOOK like they've been selected.  But if you need two actual radio buttons that work together, you are out of luck.  And in any case the thing I described before would be a huge headache compared to using JS.